# How to create a program to calculate sums of two numbers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a program where you add two decimal numbers e.g. 552.12 and 25.12 mentally and the program returns correct and wrong based on the input by the user. I tried inputting the correct answer but it still returns "Wrong". Why is it so?

```
for i in range(20):
    cash1 = round(random.uniform(0,1000), 2)  
    cash2 = round(random.uniform(0,1000), 2)  
    result = cash1 + cash2 
    print("What is the sum of", cash1,"and", cash2) 
    answer = input("Please enter your answer: ")
    if (answer == result):
        print("Correct")
    else: 
       print("Wrong")
```

Comment: `input` returns a string. `answer` is a string. `result` is an float. You can't compare a float with a string & expect it to be true.

Comment: @rdas `result` is a `float`.

Answer (score 2):

This line of code will insert a string into the variable answer:

```
answer = input("Please enter your answer: ")
```

So you need to convert answer to float type in order to compare it to result:

```
 if (float(answer) == result):
    print("Correct")
 else: 
    print("Wrong")
```

Answer (score 1):

`input()` returns a string. You need to convert it to `float` using the `float()` function.
So, change

```
    if (answer == result):
```

to

```
   if (float(answer) == result):
```

Hope that this will help you.

Comment: `result` is a `float`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, the result will be a float and it will have a long decimal place. So you have to round that to 2 decimal places. Once you have done that, you have to convert the float value to a string and compare it to the answer.

Here's the if statement that you need to change to....

```
if (answer == str(round(result,2))):
    print("Correct")
else:
    print(result)
    print("Wrong")
```

Output:

```
What is the sum of 754.14 and 229.81
Please enter your answer: 983.95
Correct
What is the sum of 177.63 and 853.05
Please enter your answer: 1022.77
1030.6799999999998
Wrong
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert the data stored in your `answer` to float. Here's the corrected code:

```
for i in range(20):
    cash1 = round(random.uniform(0,1000), 2)  
    cash2 = round(random.uniform(0,1000), 2)  
    result = cash1 + cash2 
    print("What is the sum of", cash1,"and", cash2) 
    answer = float(input("Please enter your answer: "))
    if (answer == result):
        print("Correct")
    else: 
       print("Wrong")
```

Moreover, OP already rounded result to 2 decimal places in these lines

```
cash1 = round(random.uniform(0,1000), 2)  
cash2 = round(random.uniform(0,1000), 2)
```

So no need to round them again